# How to handle input and parameter validation between layers?

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I have a 3 layer web forms application that takes user input, I know I can validate that input using validation controls in the presentation layer.  Should I also validate in the business and data layers as well to protect against SQL injection and also issues?  What validations should go in each layer?

Another example would be passing a ID to return a record.  Should the data layer ensure that the id is valid or should that happen in BLL / UI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should validate in **all layers of your application**.

What validation will occur at each layer is specific to the layer itself. Each layer should be safe to send "bad" requests to and get a meaningful response, but which checks to perform at each layer will depend on your specific requirements.

Broadly:

- User Interface - Should validate user input, provide helpful error messages and visual clues to correcting them; it should be protecting your lower layers against invalid user input.
- Business / Domain Layer - Should check arguments to methods are valid (throwing `ArgumentException` and similar when they are not) and should check that operations are possible within the constraints of your business rules; it should be protecting your domain against programming mistakes.
- Data Layer - Should check the data you are trying to insert or update is valid within the context of your database, that it meets all the relational constraints and check constraints; it should be protecting your database against mistakes in data-access.

Validation at each layer will ensure that only data and operations the layer believes to be correct are allowed to enter. This gives you a great deal of predictability, knowing information had to meet certain criteria to make it through to your database, that operations had to be logical to make it through your domain layer, and that user input has been sanitized and is easier to work with.

It also gives you security knowing that if any of your layers was subverted, there is another layer performing checks behind it which should prevent anything entering which you don't want to.

Comment: If I have a method that requires a customerId, and it is missing, should I throw a actual system exception, or just have some variables in my class for HasError, ErrorMsg, etc?  How should I distinguish between errors that are system related (like database being unavailable) and one's that are the result of invalid user input?

Comment: You will need to make the error handling relevant to the layer it is being performed in. For user input, display error messages. For methods, throw exceptions. The type of the exception and the messages provided should make clear exactly what the cause is. `ArgumentException` for problems in calling a method, `SqlException` for problems interacting with a SQL Server database, etc.

Answer (score 5):

`Should I also validate in the business and data layers as well to protect against SQL injection and also issues?`

Yes and Yes.

In your business layer code, you need to validate the input again (as client side can be spoofed), and also for your business logic, making sure the entries make sense for your application.

As for the data layer - you again need to ensure data is valid for the DB. Use parametrized queries as this will pretty much ensure no SQL injection will happen.

As for your specific question regarding the ID - the DB will know if an ID exists or not. Whether that is valid or not, depends on whether it has meaning for your business layer or not. If it purely a DB artefact (not part of your object model), than the DB needs to handle it, if it *is* a part of your object model and has significance to it, the business layer should handle it.

Comment: "Yes and Yes," is p. much the only correct answer.  
Good details too.

Comment: So for example, if I am taking a input of email address at the UI layer which will eventually be written to a field called email in the database, I should use a static utility method IsValidEmail in the UI layer (client side and server side), again in the business layer, and once more in the data layer?

Comment: In the business layer definitely, at it has _meaning_ there. In the DB layer? If it is just storage, than no.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely need to validate in your business and data layers.  The UI is an **untrusted** layer, it is always possible for somebody to bypass your client-side validation and in some cases your server-side UI validation.

Preventing SQL injection is simply a matter of parameterizing your queries.  The phrase "SQL Injection" shouldn't even exist anymore, it's been a solved problem for years and years, and yet every day I see people writing queries using string concatenation.  Don't do this.  Parameterize the commands and you will be fine.

One of the main reasons you separate your app into multiple tiers is so that each tier is reusable.  If individual tiers don't do their own validation, then they are not autonomous and you don't have proper separation of concerns.  You also can't do any thorough testing without individual components doing built-in validation.

I tend to relax these restrictions for classes or methods that are `internal` or `private` because they're not getting directly tested or used.  As long as the public API is fully-validated, private APIs can generally assume that the class is in a valid state.

So, basically, yes, every layer, in fact *every public class and method* needs to validate its own data/arguments.

---

Semantic validation, like checking whether or not a particular Customer ID is valid, is going to depend on your design requirements.  Obviously the business layer has no way of knowing whether or not an ID exists until said ID actually hits the data layer, so it can't perform this check in an advance.  Whether it throws an exception for a missing ID or simply returns `null`/ignores the error depends on exactly what the class/method is designed to do.

However, if this ID needs to be in a special format - for example, maybe you're using specially-coded account numbers ("R-12345-A-678") - then it does become the responsibility of the domain/business layer to validate the input and make sure it conforms to the correct format, especially if the consumer of your business class is trying to create a new account.

Comment: If you can deliver a world without SQL Injection be my guest.
String concatention is not the only vector for them.
This: 
http://taylorza.blogspot.com/2009/04/sql-injection-are-parameterized-queries.html
 Explains how even a parameterized query can be maligned.

Comment: @cazlab: That's a lousy example.  It just moves the string concatenation from the app logic to the database itself.  The vulnerability still only exists because of the string concatenation, and it is trivial to parameterize an `sp_executesql` statement internally.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that it still exists, and that using parametrized queries is no excuse to not sanitize your input.
You should always sanitize your input.

Don't get me wrong: I agree one should use parameterized queries, but developr was asking if he should be validating, and Yes he should.

Comment: @cazlab: The vulnerability exists because someone used `sp_executesql` without binding parameters - exactly the same as concatenating together a query on the client side.  It's no different from writing a Stored Procedure that drops several tables and allowing access to it from the UI, then complaining about a vulnerability.  "Sanitizing" user input for possible SQL injection is something you should rarely be doing in this day and age.  Please don't let me see another web page that screws up or prohibits apostrophes or worse, refuses to let me type in the word "update."

Comment: @Aaronaught and @Chris Marisic That's cool if you guys disagree with everyone else in this thread and feel that cutting corners is okay if you're doing certain things correctly.  You're free to be wrong.

Comment: @cazlab you talk about us being wrong and make statements that show you truly don't understand the difference from the view layer and presenter layer?

Comment: @cazlab: Attempting to "sanitize" user input for SQL injection is archaic and actually harmful in many cases.  Look at a site like StackOverflow where users might actually need to input SQL statements!  Hardly "cutting corners."  @Chris, thanks for the vote of confidence.

Comment: @cazlab: +1 Aaronaught is absolutely right. At the end of the day it is string concat of your sql call that creates the injection problem.

Comment: @Aaronaught I'm sure you're right that properly implemented parameterized queries are safe.  All I was saying is that you can't make assumptions about his environment, and that he should be validating anyway.  .'/

Answer (score 1):

No layer should trust data coming from another layer. The analogy I use for this is one of fiefdoms. Say you want to send a message to the king. If the message is not in the proper format it will be rejected before it ever gets to his ears. You could continue to send messages until you eventually get the format right or you could use an emissary. The job of the emissary is to help you verify that your message will be in the acceptable format so that the king will hear it.

Each layer in a system is a fiefdom. Each layer acts as an emissary to the layer to which it will send data by verifying that it will be accepted. No layer trusts data coming from outside that layer (no one trusts messages from outside the fiefdom). The database does not trust the middle layer. The middle-layer does not trust the database or the presentation layer. The presentation does not trust the user or the middle layer.

So the answer is that absolutely you should check and re-check the data in each layer.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.

Validate as input gets received in each new layer and before it gets acted upon, generally I validate such input just before it gets used or passed on to the next layer (javascript checks if it's a valid email and free of malicious input, likewise the business layer does before constructing a query using it.)

To your last question: if the ID returns a record, then it is valid, and you'd have to find the record's id to confirm whether or not it is valid, so you'd be making a lot of unnessecary lookups if you were to try that.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I do all of my validation at the Presenter layer in the Model-View-Presenter. Validation is somewhat tricky because it's really a crosscutting concern so many times.

I prefer to do it at the presenter layer because I can then shortcircuit calling to the model.

The other approach is to do the validation in the model layer but then the issue of communication of errors because you cannot easily inform other layers of errors aside from exceptions. You can always pack exceptions with data or create your own custom exception that you can attach a list of error messages or similar construct to but that always seem dirty to me.

Later when I expose my model through a web service I will implement double validation checking both in the Presenter and in the Model since it will be possible to jump the presenter layer if you call the web service. The other big advantage to this is that it decouples my validations for the presenter layer from the model since the model might only require raw validation of types to match the database whereas users of my UI I want more granular rules of what they input not just that they physically can.

Other questions: the sql injection portion that is a model concern and should not be in any middle layers. However most sql injection attacks are completely nullified when text fields don't allow special characters. The other part of this is you should almost always be using parametrized sql which makes sql injection not usable.

The question on the ID that's a model concern either it can get a record with that ID or it should return null or throw an exception for record not found depending on what convention you wish to establish.

Comment: Wrong.
The presentation layer is the WEAKEST link.

Comment: @cazlab That statement doesn't even make sense. Give one counter example that shows any fault in validation at the presenter layer. You won't be able to. The only way you could is to work with the model directly which would violate separation of concerns unless it involves a webservice on top of the model layer which in that case I already explained that.

Comment: Here's an example:
If someone bypasses the presentation layer by communicating directly with the logic layer, say by using a crafted HTTP Request packet with their own, malformed and unvalidated, input.

Comment: You're confusing presenter layer with view layer. There is no way to bypass the presenter layer. That theoretically could bypass clientside view validation but that in way would impact server side presenter validation.